# Android: Execution Failed for task app.dexDebug for Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I try to use facebook SDK for my app, but it gives app.dexDebug exception

Here's fragment from my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile project(":volley")
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
}
```

I red articles and I know that Facebook uses same item from the list, but in this case, which should I delete, so that it wont harm app and I also be able to use Facebook SDK? thanks

Error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: where is the error? post it

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add **[multiDexEnabled](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/building/multidex.html)**

> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     ...
>     minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
>     targetSdkVersion //Yours
>
>     // Enabling multidex support.
>     multiDexEnabled true
> }
>
> dependencies {
>  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
> }
> ```

2. Then you probably get `Duplicate class`

> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
>
> compile'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1'

Use one .Then **clean-Rebuild-Restart** Your Project .

Comment: @Nikoloz14 Move ahead .